# Why doesn't my blur matrix filter blur the photo, and why does it make it darker?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I am at a loss here, sorry if this question seems stupid.
I have the following code that should return a blurred image of a cat:

```
def convolve(image, kernel): #IMPLEMENT HERE
    image_copy=image.copy()
    final_img=np.empty_like(image_copy) #make empty array of same size

    for ix in range(len(image)):
        for iy in range(len(image[ix])):
            for iz in range(len(image[ix][iy])):
            # print(new_kernel[ix][iy])
                final_img[ix, iy, iz]=np.multiply(image[ix, iy, iz], kernel[ix%len(kernel), iy%len(kernel),iz])*1/9

    return final_img
new_kernel=np.ones((3,3,3))
new_kernel[0,1]=2
new_kernel[1,0]=2
new_kernel[1,2]=2
new_kernel[1,1]=4
new_kernel[2,1]=2
new_kernel[2]=3
plt.imshow(convolve(image, new_kernel))
```

Instead, it returns a darkened version of the image. How do I fix this?

Comment: is this **homework**, a class assignment, or exam task? -- your `convolve` is wrong. `% len(kernel)` is nonsense. and your indexing is insane too. `(H, W, C) = image.shape` and work with that... and review how kernels are applied. you need a bunch more loops, or use numpy to better effect. and `np.multiply` is entirely pointless for scalar values.

Comment: In the Python interactive interpreter (or, for example, in a Jupyter notebook) explore what each part of your `np.multiply` expression does. Look at the result of each indexing expression, etc. Try to understand what the code you wrote actually does. This is a process we all went through to learn to program. There are no shortcuts.

Comment: related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a16689751

Answer (score 2):

Blurring an image is the equivalent of reducing the image features, i.e we are either reducing the number of pixels, reducing the sharpness of pixels or both, that said your function does not do either, your function is simply going over the image and updating the channel, specifically if our image is

```
white = [255, 255, 255]
black = [0, 0, 0]
image = [[white, white, white],
         [white, black, white],
         [white, white, white]]
```

Then your code will change it into

```
image = [[white / 9, 2 * white / 2, white / 9],
         [2 * white / 9, 4 * black / 9, 2 * white / 9],
         [3 * white / 9, 3 * white / 9, 3 * white / 9]]
```

What you are doing is you are reducing the value of each pixel and since 0 is black and 255 is white, the closer we are to 0 the darker the pixel, that is why your image is appearing darker.


Back to blurring, we really just need 2 things:


**1. Convolution**

Convolving an image with a kernel of size `k x k x c` means we are taking a piece of the image of size `k x k x c` and multiplying it element-wise by the kernel

Then in order to blur an image we need to sum the result of our convolution and divide by `k x k`

If `k = 3`, then convolving our image with the kernel of all ones can be visualized as shown below


[image]

We can control how blurry the image gets by not convolving all the pixels and skipping some, this will force the resolution to decrease.


**2. Choosing right kernel**

The most basic blurring kernel is the all ones kernel, it just averages out every pixel, but you can experiment with others

Here is an implementation of a blurring convolution operator

```
import numpy as np
def blur(img, kernel, stride = 3):
    h, w, c = img.shape
    new_img = []

    for i in range(0, h, stride):
        row = []
        for j in range(0, w, stride):
            neighborhood = get_neighbors(img, (i, j), c)
            average = get_average(neighborhood, kernel)
            row.append(average)
        new_img.append(row)

    return np.array(new_img)

### Helper functions ###
def get_neighbors(img, loc, c):
    """
    We find all the neighbors of the pixel located at loc = (x, y) 
    within a 1 pixel radius 

    Inputs
       :img: <np.ndarray> of size (h, w, c) representing the image
       :loc: <tuple<int>> = (x, y) indicating pixel location
       :c: <int> number of channels (1 for black and white, 3 for rgb images)

    Outputs
       :returns: <np.ndarray> of size (3, 3, c) representing the neighborhood of a pixel, if a pixel is on a boundary, we will assume missing pixels are 0
    """
    h, w, _ = img.shape
    x, y = loc
    neighborhood = []
    for i in range(-1, 2):
        x_ = x + i
        row = []
        if 0 <= x_ < h: 
            for j in range(-1, 2):
                y_ = y + j
                if 0 <= y_ < w: row.append(img[x_, y_])
                else: row.append(np.zeros(c,  dtype=np.int32))
        else:
            row = np.zeros((3, c), dtype=np.int32)

        neighborhood.append(row)

    return np.array(neighborhood)

def get_average(neighborhood, kernel):
    """
    Computes the average of a neighborhood using given kernel
    Ex: 
        If kernel is [[1 1 1]
                      [1 1 1]
                      [1 1 1]]
        Then image will become
            [[1 1 1]       
             [1 0 1]   ->   [[8/9]]
             [1 1 1]]       
    """
    k_h, k_w, _ = kernel.shape
    n = k_h * k_w
    avg = (neighborhood * kernel) // n
    avg = avg.sum(0, dtype=np.int32).sum(0, dtype=np.int32)

    return avg
```

I recommend you try to implement your own blurring convolution operation and use this only as a reference.

Comment: `avg = avg.sum(0, dtype=np.int32).sum(0, dtype=np.int32)` - what is it supposed to do? I don't know Python well